# What is the class keyword before a function argument?

Tags: c++, c++11

Why does this code work? See the `class` keyword in front on the `f` function argument? What does it change if I add it?

```
struct A
{
    int i;
};

void f(class A pA) // why 'class' here?
{
    cout << pA.i << endl;
}

int main() 
{
    A obj{7};
    f(obj);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If a function or a variable exists in scope with the name identical to the name of a class type, class can be prepended to the name for disambiguation, resulting in an [elaborated type specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/elaborated_type_specifier).

You are always allowed to use an elaborated type specifier. Its major use case, however, is when you have a function or variable with an identical name.

Example from cppreference.com:

```
class T {
public:
    class U;
private:
    int U;
};

int main()
{
    int T;
    T t; // error: the local variable T is found
    class T t; // OK: finds ::T, the local variable T is ignored
    T::U* u; // error: lookup of T::U finds the private data member
    class T::U* u; // OK: the data member is ignored
}
```

Comment: So here the `class` is the same as `typename`?

Comment: @Narek: No. Try to use `typename` in this example (or in yours) and you'll see that it fails.

Comment: This answer is worded slightly incorrectly. You are *always* allowed to use an elaborated type specifier. Its major *use case*, however, is when you have a function or variable with an identical name.

Comment: @Christian Hackl; Good point to emphasize. I've made an update accordingly.