# What is the use of the class prefix in a function definition?

Tags: c++

I've come across code that has function definitions like this:

```
void VisitorPrimitiveSelector::visitObjComposite(class Object3DComposite& comp);
```

What exactly is the use of the `class` word in the parameter list? I've never seen this before and can't seem to find anything online about it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the class keyword before a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35959438/what-is-the-class-keyword-before-a-function-argument)

Answer (score 2):

It's just another way of writing `Object3DComposite& comp`. The `class` keyword isn't needed, unless there exists something named `Object3DComposite` which is not a class as well. Then the `class` is explicitly needt o tell the compiler which symbol with the same name is the expected.

Answer (score 2):

It is a forward declaration of class Object3DComposite

Answer (score 1):

Back in the days of C-that-was:

```
struct foo {};
```

did not introduce a tyoe named `foo`.  It instead introduced `struct foo`.

C programmers got around this with

```
typedef struct foo{}foo_t;
```

which introduced `foo_t` as an alias for `struct foo`.

You no longer need that (in most situations), as in C++ `struct foo` introduces a type named `foo`.  Despite that, the old syntax remains valid.

And `class` is mostly just `struct` with different default privacy rules.

Comment: In addition to what @YakkAdamNevraumont wrote, notice this. When you define `struct point {float x, y;}` and `typedef point point_t`, the way you access the member of (for example) `point_t p1 = {0.0, 0.01}` is to set `float x= p1.x` and `float y = p1.y`. In a similar way, to access the member (accessible member) of a class is: `MyClass::member`.  Read [structure](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/structures/) and [class](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/) for more information